# customize paypal android sdk source code

Tags: android, paypal, sdk, customization

is there anyway to customize paypal android sdk code source
I have looked for the source code of the library not the sample example but I didn't find it

do you have any idea

because I wan to change the display of view and add the logo of my app and something else

Comment: It may be possible using Java reflection. But honestly, it would be difficult :/ Take a look at : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

Comment: then, how could I process if I want to make my own payment view with paypal, why they didn't provide the source code of the sdk, a lot of people will want to change something according to their need, isn't it !!

Comment: no one has any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has brand and UI restrictions, preventing developers from customizing the native UI.  These restrictions are analogous to the web experience.  Since co-branding is an oft requested feature on the web, I recommend opening an issue in our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/) requesting this feature to be prioritized in the SDKs!